# How do I pass username:password in front of domain in url, flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am currently in the process of building an application, and I need to be able to make use of the fact that if you have a url like this:

```
https://username:password@domain.tld/page
```

you can use that to login on the page, however when trying to figure out where in my request that data gets passed to flask when making a new route, I am failing. I know that I can do this in other ways, however this option has some advantages for me.

**I am very aware that there are serious security implications with this, and that using this for logging in is a very bad idea, and I am not going to use it to handle user logins, but rather other data.**

If anyone can point me in a direction of how to get this information from a the request that would be lovely, thanks again.

Comment: For reference purposes, that URL scheme is a shortcut way of doing HTTP "Basic Authentication".  It avoids the browser-initiated dialog (which is ALSO insecure), but sends the same headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The username and password are available on the `authorization` attribute of the `request` object. Given code like this:

```py
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    if request.authorization:
        auth = request.authorization
        return auth.parameters
    else:
        return 'Not authenticated'
```

A request like:

```
curl http://alice:example@localhost:5000/
```

Will result in:

```
{"password":"example","username":"alice"}
```

While a request without authorization, like this:

```
curl localhost:5000
```

Will result in:

```
Not authenticated
```

Comment: brilliant, exactly what I was looking for, now I just gotta figure out the equivalent in the quart module :P